What is Robert Brandom's view of truth/objectivity of claims and does it ending being "Relativist"?
I have read a few of Brandom's papers on truth, "Why Truth is Not Important in Philosophy" and I am starting "Articulating Reasons". It is still unclear to me, even after reading some excerpts from "Making it Explicit", exactly what his view is (I plan to read the whole thing, but it's quite the undertaking).
Based on my current understanding BRandom's view of truth/objectivity goes something like this: "Truth" is a normative agreement, which is nevertheless objective because it is based on concept mastery and holding others accountable for their assertions and being held accountable for the assertions we make. In short, it is kind of a deflationary view, that tries to preserve objectivity through "correctly" following normative practices.
Example:

You say "the cat is on the mat".
By virtue of us both understanding "the cat is on the mat", we understand that the cat being or not being on the mat is what counts as such.
I take you as being committed to the cat being on the mat.
When we discover the cat is not on the mat, you are objectively wrong and the sentence is objectively false.

I am just confused about how this doesn't collapse into one of the following categories: A Peircian theory of truth or Rortian relativism.
Suppose we have two different alien lineages (Earthlings and Schmearthlings) with a completely different set of discursive commitments and concepts. Earthlings best theories are predictively incompatible with Schmearthlings best theories. Earthlings might say something which is "objective" in the Brandomian sense above, but Schmearthlings might be able to demonstrate that it is wrong. There are two was out that I see as being in keeping with my understanding of what Brandom is trying to do.

A Peircian subjunctive/regulatory notion of truth. (What all commitment holders would agree to in ideal inquiry?) Schmearthlings are right and Earthlings are wrong, they just haven't discursively clashed yet.
Relativism. Schmearthlings and Earthlings have an equal claim to truth.

I am likely confused here. Help would be greatly appreciated.

From what I recall, I don’t think that there is a Peircian side in Brandom’s work. The idea of an ideal end of inquiry is a kind of concession to the correspondence theory of truth. At the end of inquiry we will finally correspond to the world as it is. There is no such concession in Brandom. In his view, we can only ever cope (with the “world”). Correspondence is not an option. As to how Brandom differs from Rorty, this is a big question, which I cannot currently answer.
